# Realm can't user logout

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have got a problem with the realm java version. I tried to use it with Realm Mobile Platform.

I can register and sign in with the authentification with that :

```
User user = User.login(myCredentials, authURL);
```

But when I want to logout the current user with :

```
User.currentUser().logout();
```

the current user is always define with the old user value. 
How I can remove this user ?

Comment: It seems to be an unfortunate bug from our side. A fix is pending here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/3640

Comment: Apparently it will be fixed in 2.1.0

Comment: Ok ! Thanks a lot, I didn't see this fix.